# How to combine columns and pivot column values into new column at the same time within dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, pivot

I have a df that looks like this (column `10_value` needs to be next to `10_type`, not sure how to format that) :

```
 0_0_type  0_0_value 0_1_type 0_1_value 0_firstname_value 0_lastname_value 10_0_type  
   uuid        1       ID         2           test1          test1    uuid   
   uuid        2    EMAIL    email1             NaN            NaN    uuid   
   uuid        3    EMAIL    email2             NaN            NaN    uuid   
   uuid        4    EMAIL    email3           test2          test2    uuid   
   uuid        5    EMAIL    email4             NaN            NaN    uuid   
   uuid        6    EMAIL    email5           test3          test3    uuid   
   uuid        7    EMAIL    email6           test4          test4    uuid   
   uuid        8    EMAIL    email7           test5          test5    uuid   
   uuid        9    EMAIL    email8           test6          test6    uuid   

   10_0_value 10_1_type  10_1_value   10_firstname_value  10_lastname_value  
        10     EMAIL     email9             test7            test7  
        11     EMAIL    email10             test8            test8  
        12     EMAIL    email11             test9            test9  
        13     EMAIL    email12            test10           test10  
        14     EMAIL    email13            test11           test11  
        15     EMAIL    email14            test12           test12  
        16     EMAIL    email15            test13           test13  
        17     EMAIL    email16            test14           test14  
        18     EMAIL    email17            test15           test15
```

I have 1500k columns with these type of column name structure. The only difference is the number in the front is changing, in this case `0` or `10`.

I only want four pieces data which is `uuid,email,first_name,last_name`.

How do I:

1. scan the entire dataframe for the phrase `first_name` or `last_name` and stack the records on top of each other

at the same time

2. extract `EMAIL` and `uuid` into a column of their own ?

Final df should look like this:

```
   uuid    EMAIL  first_name      last_name
0       1      NaN       test1          test1
1       2   email1         NaN            NaN
2       3   email2         NaN            NaN
3       4   email3       test2          test2
4       5   email4         NaN            NaN
5       6   email5       test3          test3
6       7   email6       test4          test4
7       8   email7       test5          test5
8       9   email8       test6          test6
9      10   email9       test7          test7
10     11  email10       test8          test8
11     12  email11       test9          test9
12     13  email12      test10         test10
13     14  email13      test11         test11
14     15  email14      test12         test12
15     16  email15      test13         test13
16     17  email16      test14         test14
17     18  email17      test15         test15
```

Comment: Is the dataframe columns ordered ?

Comment: @W-B they are very random, but all have an integer in them that is changing.

Comment: Let's look at those that start with 0_.  0_type and 0_value 0_type.1 and 0_value.1, is there no 0_firstname_value nor 0_lastname_value?

Comment: If not, can we assume that that columns are order in groups of six?

Comment: There is 0_first_name. I truncated the column names because they are extremely long. And no they don’t come on groups of 6. They are spread out. Very messy data

Comment: This is so called corrupt data ...

Comment: @W-B but the pattern in the column name does exist, ideally I would like to just scan for it and stack the records.

Comment: 0_type 0_value 0_type.1 0_value.1 0_firstname_value 0_lastname_value... Okay those should be together.  Where .1 represents the emails.  Is there and 0_firstname_value.1 and 0_lastname_value.1?  And what group does that belong too if exists?  In your sample, you do have firstname_value.1 but I am not sure how to align these values.

Comment: @ScottBoston there is 0_firstname_value.1 and 0_lastname_value.1

Comment: Okay so, 0_type which has UUID and 0_type.1 which has an email can have two first names?  0_firstname_value and 0_firstname_value.1?

Comment: @ScottBoston I made a mistake, the column names were truncated on my screen, see the column name update. The integer value is changing and is appended to the front of each category.

Comment: Now, you have duplicate column naming '0_type' twice once for uuid an once for emails?

Comment: @ScottBoston I fixed the columns. Very sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay let's try this bit of code for those column naming.  First, rename your columns to move the incremented index to after a separator, ':' I choose.  Then use `pd.wide_to_long` to reshape the dataframe and lastly `filter` the dataframe to choose only the "value" columns.

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'(\d+)_(\w+)',r'\2:\1')
pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(),
                ['0_type','1_type','0_value','1_value','firstname_value','lastname_value'],
                'index',
                'Num',
                sep=':')\
  .reset_index()\
  .filter(like='value')
```

output:

```
    0_value  1_value firstname_value lastname_value
0         1        2           test1          test1
1         2   email1             NaN            NaN
2         3   email2             NaN            NaN
3         4   email3           test2          test2
4         5   email4             NaN            NaN
5         6   email5           test3          test3
6         7   email6           test4          test4
7         8   email7           test5          test5
8         9   email8           test6          test6
9        10   email9           test7          test7
10       11  email10           test8          test8
11       12  email11           test9          test9
12       13  email12          test10         test10
13       14  email13          test11         test11
14       15  email14          test12         test12
15       16  email15          test13         test13
16       17  email16          test14         test14
17       18  email17          test15         test15
```

Comment: @RustyShackleford... I guess this didn't help you.

Comment: it is close but I am getting an empty dataframe, when I run the last line. What do you think about if I standardize the column names by removing all the characters except the string after the last underscore and concat the df that way? The string after the last underscore is standardized across the board.

Comment: You'll have to try.  When you say the last line, are you talking about just '.filter...'?  If so, you can manually select the columns from the large dataframe returned.  Just remove .filter and look at what is returned.

Comment: ignore. I got it work with your solution. I changed the column names slightly to match what I had! I cant thank you enough